# About zero-width assertion does not support uncertain long-term problems

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the regular expression of python's re module to identify the 4 numbers in the string below this pattern:

> The number of qualified individuals is 13553, company is 2500, The actual number of individuals joined is 7187,compny is 1722.

I was stuck when I used the zero-width assertion to identify the number after `company is`. I don't know how to identify the last number because there are two identical `company is` and `(?<="some words")` Expressions do not support indefinite length.

```
import re
content = "The number of qualified individuals is 13553, company is 2500, The actual number of individuals joined is 7187,company is 1722."

match_first = re.search("The actual.*\d\\b", content).group()
print(match_first)

match_content = re.search("(?<=company\sis\s)+\d+", match_first).group()
print(match_content)
```

In fact, this method can also be matched, but it is cumbersome, I always feel that there is a way to match the last number with a single statement. It only matches the numbers, the others don't match, maybe because I learn regular expression. The time was too short, I spent a night studying regular expressions still didn't find a way. According to last night's understanding, it may be necessary to use recursive matching to solve it. I still need some time to finish it, but I think there must be a way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you only need to find all the digit sequences in a sentence, can't you use `re.findall("\d+", s)`?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, because the above is only a part of the content, there are unrelated numbers in other content, so I need to use the only keywords in the "actual number of individuals joined" and "company is" keywords to lock this number. So that we won't recognize other useless numbers, and the numbers and other non-keywords may change, so we need to use such a troublesome way to lock, and I also want to use simple and easy to understand. The code is implemented.

Comment: sorry, my time here is already two in the morning, I need to sleep first, tomorrow I will list the methods I have tried, thank you!